# Magento2.2.5 amazon_sales_order table does not exist?

Tags: magento-2.2.5, amazon-payment

I recently upgrated a magento from 2.2.3 to 2.2.5 and now when people place an order I am seeing errors in the system.log that seem to state that there is a table related to amazon_sales_order that the table does not exit? how do I go about creating it along with any other amazon pay related tables? Note i am not even using or have activated the amazon pay method?

```
 Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'amazon_sales_order' doesn't exist
```

looking at my database I see only the below amazon related tables

- amazon_customer
- amazon_pending_authorization
- amazon_pending_authorization
- amazon_pending_capture
- amazon_pending_refund

Comment: ok so in config.php in the etc folder i had amazon_payments set to 1 so i changed it to 0 but this wont help in the future if i want to use amazon pay so anyone know how to get magento to create the missing table?